# RSA decryption is very slow

Tags: php, performance, encryption, rsa

I've implemented RSA in php, my private key is 640 digits long and I'm using the Chinese Reminder Theorem for faster results but it still take me more than three second for a single decryption for a 50 digit long(AES key)which I think is very very slow, considering it takes no more than milliseconds on most an https sites.

```
$dec = bcmod(  bcadd(   bcmul(bcmul($q,$cp),bcpowmod(bcmod($keyrsa,$p),$dp,$p)),  bcmul(bcmul($p,$cq),bcpowmod(bcmod($keyrsa,$p),$dp,$p))   )     ,   $n );
```

This is how I've implemented it if you're interested. Almost all of the variables are pre calculated.

In python it is very fast using same algorithm but still for some reason php is slower.

1. Is there a better implementation?
2. How do most HTTPS websites do it so much faster with so much traffic?

Comment: Which version of PHP are you using, on which platform? See also: https://3v4l.org/unrRL You can put your own code in there and eval() to see the preformance.

Comment: I'm using php 7.1.7 on 000webhost, which doesn't give detail about its specs.

Comment: Perhaps spend a bit more on hosting? :-) No, really, that can make a huge difference. I also noticed this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-private-encrypt.php But to be honest, I haven't really studied this, so I can't really help you.

Comment: https://3v4l.org stopped the running of the code apparently it took a long time also on their server, openssl is for symmetric encryption not asymmetric, thanks anyways.

Comment: If you had given the values of the variables in your code I could have done some tests, but the code is incomplete, so no testing. I have a server, so I could simply see how long your code takes on mine.

Comment: https://3v4l.org/dvtK6 I'll probably change my primes anyways, the user time seems to be about 2.5 s

Comment: Thanks, yes, it does take long, around 2600 ms. And I'm running a fast server. Let me see why this is so slow.

Comment: It's the `bcpowmod()` that is slow. I noticed you use `bcpowmod(bcmod($keyrsa,$p),$dp,$p)` twice. Store it in a variable and you can half the execution time.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware YES, it now takes only 1.6 s much better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is type conversion, everytime a `bc` function is called it needs to convert the string to internal representation then convert it back into a decimal string, which then gets passed to the next function

try using GMP integer math instead, man page [here](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.gmp.php)

```
<?php
$keyrsa = gmp_init("9832475748957245");
$p = gmp_init("8354079484936541914927899085066667840301483360503839666157604136172921017528434146469774903867827180301976075982694562560689572638988092925269813627463374625291252908846201647344151611753461104963119608859115640201075591792459197160119945258486367627500121879818096099203595248003716117545512480479865709921453");
$q = gmp_init("938412744368825581535702355433426163883459511114687878154024994897102350822189947166755477679382811899594449736937158715413660429942933801527664946168421987845759422078910224872347655774496994538836516350730448938820126252589141481797770481863822310785941175596494671215977389040699889153301120914503446716507973489992786954188813");
//$cq = "90158151585243433649068545530051893622966883012518795089220114585310968302320502026270948815940384941612296625138324093461024924511161402917200931834290201708637643850750136849813026570271943168694883902320057242885955055614162225328861522256625184296048689139146938390662090382632227663474386093495477914592794162872990148364116";
//$cp = "7551459988262214427840190779497680155475105762407164553046829825327340315927179742834418691277481624391481553210225801715295088793857458100116513396506530756291114733889990865992240204940649387943199598796499358274552099683283819575613245477264444414822005200002309824389674861969207905172310540069768226872734";
$dp = gmp_init("1965665761161539274100682137662745374188584320118550509684142149687746121771396269757594095027724042423994370819457544131926958267997198335357603206461970500068530096199106269963329791000814377638381084437438974164958962774696281684734104766702674735882381618780728493930257705412639086481297054230556637628577");
//$dq = "883211994700071135563013981584401095419726598696176826497905877550213977244414067921652214286477940611383011517117325849801092169358055342614272890511455988560714750191915505762209558375997171330669662447746304883595412943613309629927313394695362174857356400561406749379743424979482248614871643213650302792007504461169681839236529");
$qtcp = gmp_init("7086386291576524054360302742239998876673708944686465411626570038380444601875306630964988910095131487662281790536626963003506657704070876201964033331286024035984707744160238401059534677753482122942131531324658709164939274183600052634838272332743659199253932999987961039598035528397374750903876542815898982226118836076739179152436733287292195730452100700462917916533108208521409272086529455286245592495898895482186435700595327952372741822199742491182942283075691359064307215568687412510144120677674012937164826009435459181454662134489129797327892892707673596353503035243628926739960488503739316122718017371542430284689864394081681732757524742");
//$d = "9684180457578041703423518212984665367413021472235946617919642829863937153436059290504589391395592577209702599096169971796160405050131992497221547725184873244919981572828194571494694548428547986158684865534112722970807920768563560619443671077664354596805006314087514740257760893103656422610790000570529248962650590971772121591956305661910290201820155312347599369833629985907639681332639927293587022614471157370529051414542594064576484579816117675667970018652822901408587669420741843654459983059048798380989538136593189533517910165268761423288024908153885735118716648190934832866700250304833422760360615089471368245425769057619094702167123265";
$n = gmp_init("7839574656134605188485705220035205297429588810857671071649234671794615790876809901837048554939289229169759246887375691454034613612011612973941252920387754531601889844670443224543324158251681703080840129241900775738273078717408596691930590872394953721223100349499416694494377865845817104018258571890428439636432369199417038685736648639886105668941162211691589720601790029355870681555006383931825756229459276736474343941175285895314774582071354222952445036285378330268675333052497389891203339480294275218891997254728399246701139093936159885498019009817278067080240490608754607645219870614833288791258716931448852885321580818328787411561305289");
$ptcq = gmp_init("753188364558081134125402477795206420755879866171205660022664633414171189001503270872059644844157741507477456350748728450527955907940736771977219589101730495617182100510204823483789480498199580138708597917242066573333804533808544057092318539651294521969167349511455654896342337448442353114382029074529457410313533122677859533299915352593909938489061511228671804068681820834461409468476928645580163733560381254287908240579957942942032759871611731769502753209686971204368117483809977381059218802620262281727171245292940065246476959447030088170126117109604470726737455365125680905259382111093972668540699559906422600631716424247105678803780548");

$gmpPowm = gmp_powm(gmp_mod($keyrsa, $p), $dp, $p);
$gmpResult = gmp_mod(gmp_add(gmp_mul($qtcp, $gmpPowm), gmp_mul($ptcq, $gmpPowm)), $n);

$dec = gmp_strval($gmpResult);

echo $dec . "\n";
```

Comment: Yesss, thank you that was exactly the problem. Just now did I notice the amount of conversion done inside of `$dec`

Comment: I ran that, and it is amazingly fast! less than 2 ms, even without storing `gmp_powm(gmp_mod($keyrsa, $p), $dp, $p)` in a variable. Wow. And 0.75 ms when I do store it in a variable.

Comment: I missed that @KIKOSoftware, added the optimisation to the answer and it runs slightly faster